# Google cardboard menu using unity 3d

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, google-cardboard

i am trying to make cardboard app like menu using unity 3d cardboard sdk. Problem is when i use the normal camera, its not working when the default manifest file is present. 
If i remove the default manifest file created, the camera is working.
Not able to find any sample for creating menu like google cardboard using unity 3d. did any one tried doing this.

Comment: Post the manifest file that doesnt work

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how the manifest factors into things, but I watched this tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mzt1rEEdeOI) on how to create 3D GUIs using Canvas and it helped me a great deal. Note that creating world-space GUIs using Canvas is only supported in Unity 4.6.

Steps

1. Download Unity 4.6+
2. Launch the scene
3. Create a new Canvas by going to GameObject -> UI -> Canvas
4. Set the render mode of the Canvas to WorldSpace
5. A large canvas will be created. Resize it and scale it down. Make sure you attach an Image component to the Canvas as this will enable you to see what you are doing both in the Scene view and the Game view.
6. Attach the relevant, buttons, panels & images to the Canvas. This will comprise your UI.

More details in the video.

Comment: Please write the main details from the video in your answer. We never know when the person who published the video removes it rendering your answer invalid for people in the future with the same question.

Comment: Any thoughts on how to manage this with both cameras? Canvas requires a camera, making it only visible in one eye.

Answer (score 0):

this issue waste my time for hours : Answer:
 1- Go to the scene ,
 2- Find EventSystem GameObject ,
 3- Find and Enable " Force Madule Active" 
4- Done!